# Sample points from a multivariate normal distribution using only the precision matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem where I can directly compute the (sparse) precision matrix (inverse of the covariance) of a multivariate normal distribution, but the covariance itself is not sparse and I don't want to invert things. I would like to sample points using the precision matrix. What's a fast way to do this?

I do know that the standard procedure is to compute the cholesky decomposition of the *covariance*, that is find lower triangular matrix L such that $LL' = \Sigma$ and then use a univariate generator to compute a vector of iid normal points $u$ so that finally the vector $z = \mu + Lu$ has the correct covariance. But that would require me computing the covariance AND then taking its Cholesky decomposition. Is there anything faster, using the fact that I have the precision matrix?

Answer (score 5):

As is pointed out in the statement, any matrix decomposition $\mathbf{L}$ such that $\mathbf{LL}^\top  = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ gives you a way to sample from the multivariate Gaussian distribution. Simply set $\boldsymbol{z} = \boldsymbol{\mu} + \mathbf{L}\boldsymbol{y}$, where $\boldsymbol{y}$ is a vector of independent univariate Gaussian variates and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ your mean vector.

The matrix decomposition is not unique, so an efficient (and convenient way) to use the sparsity is to find the Cholesky decomposition of the *precision* matrix.

Starting with the positive-definite precision matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}$, compute its sparse Cholesky decomposition as $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}=\mathbf{T}\mathbf{T}^\top$, where $\mathbf{T}$ is a lower triangular (sparse) matrix. The inverse of that Cholesky root, the lower triangular matrix $\mathbf{T}^{-1}$, can then be obtained by back-solving. There are dedicated algorithms to do these calculations efficiently using the sparse structure (these may require reordering).

Since $\mathbf{T}^{-\top} \mathbf{T}^{-1} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, you can use the matrix $\mathbf{L} \equiv \mathbf{T}^{-\top}$ in your algorithm.